# Looking for better techniques to retrieve data from the entity class into a view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an entity class with a lot of properties, each property has a display name.
I have a page, where I display the properties. For this I have created a model, where I copied the properties from the entity class.

In the controller I retrieve data from database and have an item of the entity class containing all data I need. Through reflection I copy all data to the model. In the page by using Html helpers I display name of the property and property value taken from the model.

My question is - how to implement it better? I wonder if copying properties from entity class to the model is an overkill. Moreover, I have duplicated Display Name attribute for the properties.

I was thinking of creating a property in the model representing the whole entity class, and then from the page retrieving data through the model, but using the properties of this class. However, this doesn't look like a transparent solution.

Ideas about better techniques are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are following best practice, but here are a few ways you can reduce your duplication:

1. If the fields on your entity model and your view model are identically named, you could potentially reuse the same MetaData annotation class on both models. Either that, or through inheritance on those annotation classes, reduce duplicated syntax.
2. If you don't want to do the above, use resource files for your display attributes. http://thatextramile.be/blog/2011/03/convention-based-localization-with-asp-net-mvc/ this will eliminate the need for some of the duplication. Also sets you up nicely for localisation.
3. Although I am not suggesting you should, but you *can* use your entity model as your view model as long as you set Bind Exclude annotations on it to protect yourself from property injection on the client side. It's fly by the seat of your pants type stuff, but it does reduce duplication, albeit at the risk of security.
4. You say you're using reflection? I take it you are using something similar to the fantastic Automapper? http://automapper.codeplex.com/ if not, this could also save you some time.

I hope this helps in some small way.

P.S. Always really good to see developers looking to do things better than they already have. It shows great maturity in the role and a passion for our craft; which sadly is often absent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think, these ideas are what I was looking for.